# Thymeleaf #aggregates.sum with multiple conditions

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-el

I have a list of `MyObject` as below

```
List<MyObject> myObjList;
```

where `MyObject` is class defined as below

```
 public class MyObject{

     private String status;
     private double amount;        

    }
```

Now i want to get sum of amount from the list only  if amount is not null and if status code is neither `XX` or `YY`

I know i can do this on java, but i need to do this on thymeleaf and this is what i tried but it is not working

```
aggregates.sum(myObjList.?[amount!= null && (status!='XX' || status!='YY')].![amount])
```

I am not getting any error. I am not sure what am I doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does not working mean?  You are getting the wrong number?  Regardless, your boolean expression is incorrect.  The expression reads `(status != 'XX' || status != 'YY')`, which will match all records.

For example, if `status = 'XX'` then:

```
('XX' != 'XX' || 'XX' != 'YY') => (false OR true) => true
```

The same thing happens for `YY`:

```
('YY' != 'XX' || 'YY' != 'YY') => (true OR false) => true
```

Other than that, everything seems to be working for me.  Corrected expression (parens for status not needed, unless you think it reads better):

```
${#aggregates.sum(myObjList.?[amount != null && (status != 'XX' && status!='YY')].![amount])}
```

Comment: o my god i was so much focusing something else and forgot simple boolean logic. Thank you so much.